# First degree complex equations

Tags: complex-numbers

My question is: are first degree complex equations solved in the same way as "ordinary" first degree equations.

For instance $(2+i)z=1+3i$. I would say that $z=\frac{1+3i}{2+i}$. Is this general for first degree complex equations?

Thanks.

Comment: Yes that is correct. You could clean it up a bit by multiplying the top and bottom of the fraction by $2-i$ to get $z=i+1$.

Comment: yes... the same fundamental rules apply.  The same thing added to equal things makes equal things.  The same thing multiplied by equal things makes equal things,